# Select date range in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql database to store 10 years of data but when I try to run a query to select the data from date range it give a weird output, my Query is

select  * from   test.table_1
where  date_ >= '12-03-2014' and date_  <= '12-05-2014'

and my output is :[image]

please guide what to do??

I don't know much about sql queries so I haven't tried much, but I want to select data from my sql table using start date and end date, i.e., if I enter start date as 14-08-2022 and end date as 31-08-2022 then it should return data only from 14th aug to 31st aug of year 2022.

Comment: Try using this format for dates in the query: `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.  You can also use `where date_ between '2022-08-14' and '2022-08-31'`.  (If `date_` is a date or datetime data type)

Comment: What is the field type of your `_date` column?

Comment: your `date_` column is being treated as a string,, not as a date. You need to convert the strings to dates (and this will be inefficient if y need to do this for every select)

Comment: recommended reading: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/422047/should-i-use-date-or-varchar-in-storing-dates-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you "date_" column is a string that looks like a date - so you may have to convert those strings to dates to make the necessary date range work.

```
select
      STR_TO_DATE(date_, '%d-%m-%Y') real_date
    , t.*
from your_table t
where STR_TO_DATE(date_, '%d-%m-%Y')  >= STR_TO_DATE('12-03-2014', '%d-%m-%Y') 
  and STR_TO_DATE(date_, '%d-%m-%Y')  <= STR_TO_DATE('12-05-2014', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Ultimately this isn't efficient and it may be worthwhile changing how you store that column so that it is a date data type. (i.e. NOT a string.)

**nb** I have had to assume the date format %d-%m-%Y as you have only use 12 in the first position so the date format might be %m-%d-%Y

---

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
  date_ VARCHAR(10)
);

 
INSERT INTO your_table (date_)
VALUES
  ('12-02-2013'),
  ('12-03-2014'),
  ('12-04-2014'),
  ('12-05-2014'),
  ('12-07-2016'),
  ('12-04-2017'),
  ('12-05-2018');


select
    date_
  , STR_TO_DATE(date_, '%d-%m-%Y') real_date
from your_table
where STR_TO_DATE(date_, '%d-%m-%Y')  >= STR_TO_DATE('12-03-2014', '%d-%m-%Y') 
  and STR_TO_DATE(date_, '%d-%m-%Y')  <= STR_TO_DATE('12-05-2014', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

| date_ | real_date |
| --- | --- |
| 12-03-2014 | 2014-03-12 |
| 12-04-2014 | 2014-04-12 |
| 12-05-2014 | 2014-05-12 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X-OBbLiS)

Comment: I have tried to use the STR_TO_DATE function but if I use this output is null, and yes my format is %d-%m-%Y; Any other solution? cause my data base is created by Citect Scada and   it writes the data in string format only

Comment: My error - sorry - I forgot to convert the column to match the filtering values. The query has been amended.